# display json data in the django template

Tags: ajax, json, django, forms, model

i am trying to save the form values using `ajax`. i have already done that, now the form data is being saved into db. what i want now is to display that saved data in that django template only without refreshing it. but on form submission json data string(only the result) is being displayed

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class TestModel(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=255)
```

views.py

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.utils import simplejson
from vijayapp.forms import *
from django.http import *
from vijayapp.models import *
def main(request):
   return render_to_response('index.html',
        {'form':TestForm()}, RequestContext(request))

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
            form = TestForm(request.POST)
            #message = 'something wrong'
            if form.is_valid():
                message=request.POST['title'] #model field name
                form.save()
                dict = {}
                dict['value']=message
                #return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': message}))
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dict), content_type="application/json") 

    else:

        form = TestForm()


    return render_to_response('index.html',
        {'form':TestForm()}, RequestContext(request))
```

index.html

```
    <body>
    <h1>Leave a Suggestion Here</h1>
        <div class="message"></div>
        <div class="hello">
            <form action="/forms/" method="POST" id="MY_FORM">{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }} 
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Feedback" id="button"/>
            </form>
            <p></p><p></p>
            <div id="result">
            </div>
        </div>

</body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#button").click(function() {
e.preventDefault();
var input_string1 = $(".textclass").val();
alert(input_string1);
$.ajax({
url :"forms",
type : "POST",
dataType: "json",
data: $(this).serialize(),
success : function(json) {
$('#result').html(json.value);
alert(json['value']);
},
error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
alert("wrong entry");
}
});
return false;
});
});
</script>


forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from vijayapp.models import TestModel
from django import forms 

class TestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        widgets={
                      "title":forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Name','name':'Name','id':'common_id_for_imputfields','class':'textclass'}),


                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are getting json data as a string so what you can do it is parse the json in your jquery code using $.parseJson. now you will get a data-structure(dict,tuple,list) of your data.Now you can display each data from your data-structure(dict,tuple,list).